# Printing a string between two characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a python script that will extract specific parts of lines in a text file and print them out. The part of that line is always between two specific characters. For example, I need to print everything between `"Ghost: "` and `"("`.

I've tried importing `re` and using it to search a string for characters, but I failed.

The file looks something like this:

```
Ghost: john.doe.1 {} ...
Ghost: john.walker.4 {} ...
Ghost: john.johnny.3 {} ...
Ghost: john.craig.6 {} ...
...
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
john.doe.1
john.walker.4
john.johnny.3
john.craig.6
```

Comment: _I've tried importing re and using it to search a string for characters, but I failed._ -> Please show us what you have tried

Comment: You say you want everything between "Ghost: " and "(", but there are no parentheses in your data. Shouldn't you be looking for "{" instead?

Comment: Could you please describe exactly how your text file looks like, e.g. are there spaces before the first "stopword", are there spaces in the text you want to extract. Depending on that we can decide if you need a regex or if a simple split is sufficent

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, you can do:

```
re.search('((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(\\.)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(\\.)(\\d+)', text).group()
```

Output:

```
john.doe.1
john.walker.4
john.johnny.3
john.craig.6
```

Logic:

```
'((?:[a-z][a-z]+))' - looks for word (a-z)
'(\\.)'             - looks for dot
'((?:[a-z][a-z]+))' - looks for word (a-z)
'(\\.)'             - looks for dot
'(\\d+)'            - looks for digit (0-9)
```

Answer (score 0):

split the string on whitespace and then print 2nd substring i.e

```
print(string.split(' ')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use split method and extract the required info

```
word="Ghost: john.doe.1 {} ..."
word=word.split(":")[1]
print(word.split()[0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
john.doe.1
```